# Spacing issue in math environment with xeCJK package

Tags: math-mode, spacing, xecjk

I didn't notice until today that use `\(...\)` and `$...$` with `xeCJK` (or`ctex`) will produce different results, see the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{SimSun}

\begin{document}

甲\(e^{i\pi}+1=0\)甲

乙$e^{i\pi}+1=0$乙

\end{document}
```

that gives

[image]

Notice the missing space in front of the first equation. Though it can be manually fixed, I tried adding

```
\renewcommand{\CJKecglue}{\ }
```

but this command seems affect only `$...$` environment. 
I want to know if this is intentional or not; if not, how to fix it? More fundamentally, why is `\(...\)` being treated differently than `$...$`?

Comment: I think it is preferred to put spaces between CJK characters and math equations explicitly.

Comment: Testing with texlive2022 and xeCJK v3.8.9, I find there are normal spaces in both situations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only difference between `\(` and `$` (when there are no errors raised by the former) is that `\(` issues `\relax`:

```
%% latex.ltx, line 4226
\def\({\relax\ifmmode\@badmath\else$\fi}
```

If I try manually adding `\relax` before `$`, I get the same result as with `\(`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{STFangsong}
%\setCJKmainfont{SimSun}

\begin{document}

乙\(e^{i\pi}+1=0\)乙

乙\relax$e^{i\pi}+1=0$乙

乙$e^{i\pi}+1=0$乙

\end{document}
```

[image]

I don't really know what's creating this behavior, but the culprit is certainly `\relax` that shouldn't be taken away from `\(`. One way out seems to be

```
\makeatletter
\protected\def\({\ifmmode\@badmath\else$\fi}
\makeatother
```

that doesn't require the `\relax` because it won't be untimely expanded in table cells. The output of the above document, after adding the three lines in the preamble is

[image]

which seems to be what you're looking for: only the explicit `\relax` gives the wrong spacing.

For completeness, add also

```
\protected\def\){\ifmmode\ifinner$\else\@badmath\fi\else\@badmath\fi}
```

before `\makeatother`.